# Is there a method to get all the data in IBM Rational Team Concert

Tags: rtc

Now I want to use data warehouse technology to analysis RTC data. The first step is getting data from RTC , but I don't know how and what method used  to get data from RTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTC uses embedded data warehouse. You can write your own BIRT or Cognos reports there instead of using your own solutions.
You can find more information on following jazz.net forum posts:

- https://jazz.net/forum/questions/67909/what-are-the-recommendations-for-birt-v-rrdi-reports
- https://jazz.net/forum/questions/62171/rrdi-amp-birt-roadmap

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data you are after (Work Items? Source Control data like change sets or baselines? Build Records?)

For work items, a good way to export data is to:

- build a query which select the work item you want based on your criteria
- export them as a spreadsheet (csv format) (see "[Copying work items between repositories using CSV export and import](https://jazz.net/library/article/522)")

Otherwise, there is [Rational Team Concert plain Java API's](https://jazz.net/library/article/1229) (that I mention in "[Is there an API available to directly pull RTC data through Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22033626/6309)"), which you can see used in "[Adding roles to users in team area in RTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341621/6309)".

That API can allow you to access any data you want (provided your authentication grants you the right access level) in RTC: not just work items, but all other data too.